# (T/F) A finite group $G$ has a subgroup of index $2$ if and only if its abelianized group $G/[G,G]$ has even order.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I am trying to decide if the following statement is true.

A finite group $G$ has a subgroup of index $2$ if and only if its abelianized group $G/[G,G]$ has even order.

I can't think of any counter examples because I have a hard time finding the subgroup $G/[G,G]$ from known non-abelian groups.

My attempt to prove $\implies$ is as fallows:

$|G|=2|H|\implies G/[G,G]=2|H|/|[G,G]|$. If $G$ is abelian, then $[G,G]=\{e\}$ and we are done.

For the other case, I am not so sure about some things. If $[G,G]\ne G$ and $|[G,G]|\ne 2$  then must $[G,G]$ divide $|H|$? I am not sure what to do if $[G,G]$ has order 2.

I am not sure what to do for the other direction

I would love any help on the proof or a counter example.

This is not an assignment, it is a old masters exam t/f question.

Answer (score 5):

You need the following two facts:

1. For a finite abelian group $A$, if the integer $m$ divides $|A|$, then $A$ has a subgroup of index $m$.
2. If $H$ is normal in $G$, and $G/H$ is abelian, then $[G,G]\le H$.

Now if $G$ has a subgroup of index 2 (call it $H$), then $G/H$ is abelian, and thus $[G,G]\le H$.  This means $|G/[G,G]| = 2\cdot|H/[G,G]|$, so $G/[G,G]$ has even order.

For the converse, if $G/[G,G]$ has even order, then by the first fact there's a subgroup of index 2 in $G/[G,G]$, call it $K$.  The preimage of $K$ in $G$ is also a subgroup of index 2.

Comment: How can I show the very last line is true? I am not sure which map you are referring to when you say preimage.

Comment: @tmpys: there is the quotient map $f:\ G\rightarrow G/[G,G]$. If $K$ is the subgroup of index 2 in $G/[G,G]$, then $f^{-1}(K)$ is a subgroup of index 2 in $G$, by one of the isomorphism theorem (3 or 4, depending how you order them).

Comment: @tmpys: any other questions? If I've answered your question fully, please consider marking it accepted.